# Arrastrar o mover un elemento dialog con el raton

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Quisiera saber como puedo hacer para mover un dialog con el raton, solo con codigo javascript y css, sin usar otras librerias como Jquery Bootstrap, etc.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Prueba</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('load', init, false);

        function init(){
            var botonAbrir = document.querySelector('input[value="abrir"]');
            var botonCerrar = document.querySelector('input[value="cerrar"]');
            var dialogo = document.querySelector('dialog[data-name="dialogo1"]');

            botonAbrir.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                dialogo.showModal();
            },false);
            botonCerrar.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                dialogo.close();
            }, false)
        }

    </script>

    <style>
        dialog{
            overflow: auto;
            resize: both;
        }
    </style>

    <input type="button" value="abrir">
    <dialog data-name="dialogo1">
        <p>
            Quiero arrastrar este dialog con el mouse, es decir cambiarlo de posision o ubicacion
        </p>
        <input type="button" value="cerrar">
    </dialog>
</body>
</html>
```

Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una opción utilizando los eventos de drag & drop.

Como puedes ver en el ejemplo le he añadido el atributo `draggable` al diálogo.

En el evento `dragstart` del diálogo calculo y almaceno la posición de la esquina superior del diálogo respecto a la del ratón, para calcular correctamente la posición final en el evento `drop`.

En el evento `dragover` del `body` anulo el comportamiento por defecto del evento (que no permite arrastrar elementos sobre él) para poder arrastrar el diálogo por toda la página.

En el evento `drop` del `body` calculo la posición final del diálogo a partir de la posición del ratón y del offset almacenado.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', init, false);

function init(){
    var botonAbrir = document.querySelector('input[value="abrir"]');
    var botonCerrar = document.querySelector('input[value="cerrar"]');
    var dialogo = document.querySelector('dialog[data-name="dialogo1"]');

    botonAbrir.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        dialogo.showModal();
    },false);
    botonCerrar.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        dialogo.close();
    }, false);
    
    dialogo.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e){
      var style = getComputedStyle(e.target, null);
      e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain',
        (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue('left'),10) - e.clientX)
        + ',' + 
        (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue('top'),10) - e.clientY));
    }, false);
    
    document.body.addEventListener('dragover', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }, false);
    
    document.body.addEventListener('drop', function(e){
      var offset =
        e.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain").split(',');
      dialogo.style.left = 
        (e.clientX + parseInt(offset[0],10)) + 'px';
      dialogo.style.top = (e.clientY + parseInt(offset[1],10)) + 'px';
      e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
}
```

```css
dialog{
    overflow: auto;
    resize: both;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="abrir">
<dialog data-name="dialogo1" draggable="true">
    <p>
        Quiero arrastrar este dialog con el mouse, es decir cambiarlo de posision o ubicacion
    </p>
    <input type="button" value="cerrar">
</dialog>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes realizar asociando un evento al `dialog`. En este caso yo he asociado el evento `click` al `dialog` y, cuando este evento es lanzado, llamo a una función que he llamado `muevete`.

En esa función, y mediante una variable booleana, controlo si le hemos dado click para mover el `dialog` o para dejarlo posicionado en algún lugar. En caso de que le hayamos dado click para mover el elemento le asocio también un evento `mousemove` o, en caso contrario, elimino esa asociación a dicho evento.

En la función asociada al evento `mousemove` obtengo las coordenadas en las que se encuentra el ratón y posiciono el `dialog` en esas coordenadas.

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
var seMueve = false;
 
function init(){
    var botonAbrir = document.querySelector('input[value="abrir"]');
    var botonCerrar = document.querySelector('input[value="cerrar"]');
    var dialogo = document.querySelector('dialog[data-name="dialogo1"]');

    botonAbrir.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        dialogo.showModal();
    },false);
    botonCerrar.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        dialogo.close();
    }, false);
    
    dialog.addEventListener('click', muevete, false);
}

function muevete(){
  if(!seMueve){
    dialog.addEventListener('mousemove', modificarCoordenadasDialog, false);
    seMueve = true;
  }else{
    dialog.removeEventListener('mousemove', modificarCoordenadasDialog, false);
    seMueve = false;
  }
}

function modificarCoordenadasDialog(e){
  dialog.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
  dialog.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
};
```

```css
dialog{
  overflow: auto;
  resize: both;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="abrir">
<dialog id="dialog" data-name="dialogo1">
    <p>
        Quiero arrastrar este dialog con el mouse, es decir cambiarlo de posision o ubicacion
    </p>
    <input type="button" value="cerrar">
</dialog>
```